# C# Entity Framework Group By Tie Breaker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a class called `Person` defined like so:

```cs
public class Person {
    string Name; // "Joe", "Alex", etc.
    string State; // "Minnesota", "Texas", etc.
    int Age; // "12", "23", etc.
}
```

I'm using PostgresQL as my backing database w/ EF Core to bind the `person` table to the `Person` class.

I would like to perform a query that returns a `List<Person>` of the oldest person in each state. For example, if I had:

```
Person p1 = new{
   Name = "Joe",
   State = "Minnesota",
   Age = 34
};
Person p2 = new{
  Name = "Alex",
  State = "Minnesota",
  Age = 55
};
Person p3 = new{
  Name = "George",
  State = "Texas",
  Age = 62
}
```

I would like to perform a query that returns `p2` and `p3` (the order of `p2` and `p3` within the resultant list doesn't matter).

Right now, I'm using the following query:

```cs
List<Person> oldestByState = await _context.Person.GroupBy(x => x.State).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Age).First()).ToListAsync();
```

The issue with this is that C# doesn't know how to translate it into SQL. I get an error that `x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Age)` can't be translated.

I know that a quick fix would be to do the grouping on the client, but I'd prefer to run the query on the database by fixing the Linq query.

What query should I use to return a list of the oldest people in each state that is compatible with Linq to PostgresQL translation?

EF Core: 5.0.7
Npgsql: 5.0.6

Comment: don't have a database available to test right now if EF can translate, but you might try the following selector: `.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Age == x.Max(f=>f.Age)))`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Unfortunately, it looks like it couldn't translate that either. Good idea though.

Comment: well, this use case is kind of a tricky one; i had the same case (with timestamps) a few years ago when i was working with php/mysql mostly. i can only recall i did som very hacky join-trickery. which only worked because in that use case, timestamps were unique.

Comment: it's a long shot, but give this a go `.Select(x => new {State= x.Key, Age = x.Max(e => e.Age)}).Join(_context.Person, e => e, e => new {e.State, e.Age}, (k, db) => db)` (and if it works, has some caveats - performance won't be great, and if age is not unique per state, you'll get duplicates) if it doesn't work, maybe it'll at least give you some new perspectives to think about the problem

Comment: Please always mentions the exact version when working with Entity Framework. This is probably EF core >= v3, which doesn't support this usage of `GroupBy`. Also, give exact exception messages, that would also have indicated the EF version. Finally, this is not LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold I fixed both of these issues. What alternatives do I have? It's not the end of the world to just eat the cost of client side filtering, but I'm curious if there is a way to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with SQL Server and the error received from EF is that "`First` can only be used as a final operator, try `FirstOrDefault`." Using `FirstOrDefault` worked returning the expected oldest row.

```
await _context.Person
    .GroupBy(x => x.State)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Age).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToListAsync();
```

If it still doesn't work with PostgreSQL then it may be a limitation of that provider.

Edit:
One possible work-around, pending a fix from the npgsql team, would be to use a raw SQL query. For my test schema which is a bit different, EF for SQL Server produced:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
    [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Limit1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Limit1].[Age] AS [Age], 
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[State] AS [State]
        FROM [dbo].[Persons] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Distinct1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project2].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], [Project2].[Age] AS [Age], [Project2].[State] AS [State]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent2].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
            [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent2].[Age] AS [Age], 
            [Extent2].[State] AS [State]
            FROM [dbo].[Children] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Distinct1].[State] = [Extent2].[State]
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[Age] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
```

Then executed by:

```
await _context.Person.FromSqlRaw(@"    SELECT 
    [Limit1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
    [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Limit1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Limit1].[Age] AS [Age], 
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[State] AS [State]
        FROM [dbo].[Persons] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Distinct1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project2].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], [Project2].[Age] AS [Age], [Project2].[State] AS [State]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent2].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
            [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent2].[Age] AS [Age], 
            [Extent2].[State] AS [State]
            FROM [dbo].[Children] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Distinct1].[State] = [Extent2].[State]
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[Age] DESC ) AS [Limit1]").ToListAsync();
```

Ugly as &*^, and may not match your schema but if you can write a query that returns the data then provided it returns the entity you want, EF should be able to populate it. This would be a lot more complicated if you are trying to return a more complex object graph. (I.e. Person with many columns and related entities) In those cases I would recommend running two queries, one that does the grouping and selection that just returns PersonId, then use those PersonIds to fetch the relevant Persons with their related data by ID.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still getting errors with PostgreSQL. It must be an issue specific to it.

Comment: Hmm, that would be a bit of a brick wall unfortunately. You may need to consider a less efficient work-around and try opening an issue with the npgsql team (https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues)  It should be pretty easy for them to reproduce and it might get fixed if it is a legal operation with other relational DBs.

Comment: I've expanded the answer with a potential work-around until npgsql possibly extend the provider to cater for this type of query. The SQL may not work as-is with PostgreSQL, but should serve as a starting point to try.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. While ugly, it is a workaround. Looks like as @GertArnold mentioned, EF Core doesn't support the group by query I'm using, so it seems like I'm going to have to do this with raw SQL in order for it to work.